# How to get data where the whole column is NOT NULL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to pull data where a specific column is completely not null.  It should only return the data if ALL of the rows in the column meet that requirement. Doing simply IS NOT NULL will not work.  In short, I am trying to find contracts where all of the products on that contract has been terminated and to only return that data.

Here is what I have so far, its barebone:

```
SELECT     
  T0.CustomerCode
, T0.CustomerName
, T1.ContractID
, T1.StartDate
, T1.TerminationDate
, T2.ProductRecordID
, T2.ProductSN
, T2.CompanySN
, T2.ProductRecordStatus     
FROM 
T0  
INNER JOIN T1 ON T0.ContractID = T1.ContractID
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ProductRecordID = T2.ProductRecordID    
WHERE T0.ProductRecordStatus = 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be to count null value in the specified column and check if this number is equal to zero.

```sql
DECLARE @nullCount int = 1;

SELECT
    @nullCount = COUNT(1)
FROM
    [your_table]
WHERE
    [your_column] IS NULL;

IF @nullCount = 0
    SELECT

    T0.CustomerCode , T0.CustomerName , T1.ContractID , T1.StartDate , T1.TerminationDate , 
    T2.ProductRecordID , T2.ProductSN , T2.CompanySN , T2.ProductRecordStatus

    FROM T0
    INNER JOIN T1 ON T0.ContractID = T1.ContractID INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ProductRecordID = 
    T2.ProductRecordID

    WHERE T0.ProductRecordStatus = 'A';
```

in this way if you have one or more null values the query is not even performed.